How to reduce running time? Execution time exceeded
Excuse my grammar Im dyslexic:
The main issue is that after calculating all the lags and flows at the ISIN level, when I try to do the final grouping by bucket, asset class, and date, I'm forced to re-aggregate those numeric columns including the lag based calculations. I have tried grouping before the lags to avoid having to aggregate them later, but using LAG(sum()) for every case is efficient zero.
One of my ideas was to first aggregate at the ISIN level, then running all the Lag() and flow calculations on those results and finally doing a simple roll/up to bucket/asset class/date without redoing the sums again: hence

Pre-aggregate at the ISIN level,
Compute LAGs and flows without re-aggregating,
Group by and do simple aggregations.

I believe this works but it breaks since it takes several minutes.
This is my last attempt (btw I want to do a group by at the end with all the data, but cant if this is failing):
WITH TempTable AS (
    SELECT 
        f1.*,
        ISNULL(t3.USD, 0) AS AUM,
        ISNULL(t3.Pos, 0) AS Pos,
        COALESCE(t4.Price, t3.V_price) AS Price,
        t3.V_price AS V_price
    FROM (
        SELECT 
            t2.R_date,
            t1.S_type,
            t1.Int,
            t1.ISIN
        FROM (
            SELECT DISTINCT S_type, Int, ISIN
            FROM [p_funds].[C_disaggregated_AUMs]
        ) t1
        CROSS JOIN (
            SELECT DISTINCT R_date
            FROM [p_funds].[C_disaggregated_AUMs]
        ) t2
    ) f
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT R_date, S_type, Int, ISIN, SUM(USD) AS USD, 
               SUM(Pos) AS Pos, AVG(V_price) AS V_price
        FROM [p_funds].[C_disaggregated_AUMs]
        GROUP BY R_date, S_type, Int, ISIN
    ) t3 
    ON f.R_date = t3.R_date 
    AND f.S_type = t3.S_type 
    AND f.Int = t3.Int 
    AND f.ISIN = t3.ISIN
    LEFT JOIN [p_funds].[b_data] t4 
    ON f.ISIN = t4.ISIN AND f.R_date = t4.R_date
)
, Agg AS (
    SELECT 
        TempTable.R_date,
        TempTable.S_type,
        TempTable.Int,
        TempTable.ISIN,
        SUM(TempTable.AUM) AS AUM,
        SUM(TempTable.Pos) AS Pos,
        AVG(TempTable.Price) AS Price,
        AVG(V_price) AS V_price
    FROM TempTable
    GROUP BY 
        TempTable.R_date,
        TempTable.S_type,
        TempTable.Int,
        TempTable.ISIN
)
, Lags AS (
    SELECT 
        Agg.R_date,
        Agg.S_type,
        Agg.Int,
        Agg.ISIN,
        Agg.AUM,
        LAG(Agg.AUM, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY Agg.S_type, Agg.Int, Agg.ISIN 
                              ORDER BY Agg.R_date) AS AUM_lag,
        Agg.Pos
    FROM Agg
)
SELECT TOP 100
    Lags.*,
    CASE
        WHEN t4.Assc = 'Ate' THEN 'Aes'
        WHEN t4.Assc IS NOT NULL THEN t4.Assc
        WHEN Lags.S_type IN ('AFT', 'BOV', 'CEQ', 'DAX', 'EGO', 'FIC', 'GUV', 'HAP') THEN 'Ey'
        WHEN Lags.S_type IN ('JOR', 'LIV', 'NEX', 'OTX', 'PEX', 'REZ', 'TEK', 'VAP') THEN 'Fme'
        WHEN Lags.S_type IN ('WEX', 'YUV', 'ZOR', 'QAP', 'MEV', 'KIX', 'LOP', 'NIR') THEN 'Ca'
        WHEN Lags.S_type IN ('POL', 'TIX', 'VOR', 'WIM', 'XEN', 'YAL', 'PAX', 'VEX') THEN 'Aes'
        WHEN Lags.S_type IN ('ZEP', 'LOK', 'RIM', 'GAX', 'BIX', 'FEZ', 'JAM', 'KOP') THEN 'Rate'
        ELSE 'Other'
    END AS category,
    CASE
        WHEN t4.c_bucket = 'Ate' THEN 'Aes'
        WHEN t4.c_bucket IS NOT NULL THEN t4.c_bucket
        WHEN Lags.S_type IN ('ARB', 'BEX', 'CRU', 'DEX', 'EPI', 'FLO', 'GAM', 'HUX') THEN 'Ls'
        WHEN Lags.S_type IN ('IRL', 'JAX', 'KEP', 'LOZ', 'MUV', 'NIB', 'OXT', 'PIR') THEN 'Fme'
        WHEN Lags.S_type IN ('QIV', 'REX', 'SOB', 'TIV', 'UVY', 'WIT', 'XEL', 'YOG') THEN 'Ca'
        WHEN Lags.S_type IN ('ZIP', 'ZUM', 'FOX', 'LAG', 'VIM', 'JIB', 'GLY', 'ORB') THEN 'Aes'
        ELSE 'Other'
    END AS c_bucket
FROM Lags
LEFT JOIN [p_funds].[L_bucks] t4
ON Lags.ISIN = t4.ISIN;



Please provide a small example of input and desired output.  Consider a "self" JOIN instead of using LAG.  Re first paragraph:  consider using Grammarly.

If it times out as a single action, break it down into separate actions.

create a table to hold the results of the bit containing the 3 select statements following the first FROM.
Repeat for the process for the next select with the group by clause.
Index both of these tables on the columns to be used in the join.
Run the rest of the query against these 2 tables.
Empty the tables ready for the next time.

